# MathML is rendered poorly with Firefox on Windows XP but rendered well on Linux

Tags: html, firefox, mathml

Here is a MathML sample code I am using to test MathML rendering.

Demo URL: http://jsfiddle.net/3ak4P/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>MathML demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
math {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<math>
<mrow>
  <munder>
    <mo>&sum;</mo>
    <mrow>
      <mi>p</mi>
      <mtext>&nbsp;prime</mtext>
    </mrow>
  </munder>
  <mi>f</mi>
  <mo stretchy="false">(</mo>
  <mi>p</mi>
  <mo stretchy="false">)</mo>
  <mo>=</mo>
  <msub>
    <mo stretchy="false">&int;</mo>
    <mrow>
      <mi>t</mi>
      <mo>&gt;</mo>
      <mn>1</mn>
    </mrow>
  </msub>
  <mi>f</mi>
  <mo stretchy="false">(</mo>
  <mi>t</mi>
  <mo stretchy="false">)</mo>
  <mo>&ThinSpace;</mo>
  <mo mathvariant="italic">d</mo>
  <mi>&pi;</mi>
  <mo stretchy="false">(</mo>
  <mi>t</mi>
  <mo stretchy="false">)</mo>
</mrow>
</math>
</body>
</html>
```

Output with Firefox 8 on Windows XP:

[image: With Firefox on Windows XP]

Output with Firefox 8 on Debian GNU/Linux:

[image: With Firefox on Windows XP]

Now, considering that one can't insist the users of a website to install new fonts, etc. what are the possible ways to ensure that Windows users also have a good experience browsing math formulas written with MathML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer from the main guy working on Firefox MathML now (Frédéric Wang), though I doubt it will make you happy in the short-term:

Users need to install STIX or Asana fonts to get a decent MathML rendering. Maybe one can use downloadable fonts to force these fonts to be used on a given Web page, but I never tried.

Two bugs that could be interesting:

- Allow downloading STIX fonts / bundle STIX fonts with firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=295193
- Support for MathJax fonts: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701758